# Nested imports in postcss

Tags: css, import, postcss

I'd like to use nested imports in vue component, like:

```html
<style lang="postcss">
@import '../pcss/main.pcss';
</style>
```

What plugin can solve this problem? Postcss-import, postcss-partial-import dont work in this case. I've tried to use postcss-nested-import, which provides the following syntax for import:

```css
@nested-import "/path/to/file/";
```

but parser doesn't recognize this syntax.
postcss.config.js is:

```
module.exports = (api) => {
    return {
      syntax: 'postcss-scss',
      parser: 'postcss-scss',
      plugins: [
        'postcss-simple-vars',
        'postcss-hexrgba',
        ['postcss-prepend-imports', {
          path: 'shared',
          files: [path.join(__dirname, "./resources/assets/pcss/variables/index.pcss"),]
        }],
        'postcss-partial-import',
        'postcss-import',
        'postcss-nested',
        'postcss-nesting',
        'postcss-custom-media',
      ]
    }
};
```